# Dozer copy UUID to UUID

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, uuid, dozer

I have a problem with the `UUID` field when trying to copy a class to another.
example(spring boot,jpa ecc): I have 2 classes (equals) one is an entity and one is a model. When I'm copying for example from the entity to the model, dozer can't copy the right value of uuid but create a new one.

```
public class Entity{

    private UUID id;
    private string nome;
    //getter and setter and constructurs
}

public class Model{

    private UUID id;
    private string nome;
    //getter and setter and constructurs
}
```

If for example the entity is:

uuid id= "aaa-111-222" string name="example"

After doing

Model model=dozer.map(entity,Model.class)

The model id is uuid id="bss-555-555" ,name="example"

Why??
How can I convert it rigth? I see that this problem is caused because dozer can't find a constructor in UUID class (if I'm right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using an old version of Dozer.

This issue was addressed by Dozer time ago:

https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/83

I have just tried version 6.1.0

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
     <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
     <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and it works fine.

Can you confirm your version?

Comment: tnx so much! have a nice day